# Magmi - Which field in the CSV file is referring to FULL PRICE? + Alternative for category_ids?

Tags: magento, csv, magmi

I'm pretty new in this whole magmi, magento and it is a little bit confusing..
a Few questions:

1. There are two prices, one is an original price given by a supplier, and the second price is the one given by me, the one i want to show the visitors. What am i supposed to write in the csv file in order to show "my price"?  + How can i automatically reduce for instance 20% of the original price, or on the other hand increase it by 20%?
2. Is there an alternative for "category_ids?" id like to put it by its name,
   instead of "17"- "Cars", am i being clear enough?
3. This is my csv:

manufacturer    categories  in_depth    dimension   qty name    sku model   thumbnail   price   price1xx    has_options short_description   image   upc weight  shipment_type   store   websites    attribute_set

under attribute_set- i wrote DEFAULT
under websites - i wrote all the name of the subdomains
under categories - i wrote THE NAME OF EACH CATEGORY - EXAMPLE-CARS

does it seem ok to you?

1. Do you have an example of a full working csv file i could use?

tnx in advanced!!!

Answer (score 2):

In relation to your question about **categories**, Magmi has a plugin called *On the fly category creator/importer*.

The way it works is pretty simple, add a field in your csv file with the name *categories* and for every product, add relevant categories in comma separated format:

`parentcategory/subcategory,other category`

Non existing categories in Magento will be automatically created.

In order to use it you have to activate it. You can do it through the Magmi web interface (don't forget to click on *save profile* before running the application) or directly editing the `plugins.conf` file.

Comment: could you guys help me some more?

Comment: I can't look into all of the products, some are working, but some arent, when i click on a product to see more details and purcase i get this eror X 30! :
cache_dir must be a directory­­

Comment: Why don't provide more details and post your comment as a new question?

Comment: Just a note to people who come across this question, the on the fly category imported plugin doesn't come as default. You have to download the ZIP from the Magmi site and install. Might save someone the 20 confused minutes I just wasted!

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here's the templates I've used to import successfully with magmi:

For product import (just the header):

```
store,websites,attribute_set,type,category_ids,sku,name,price,special_price,cost,weight,status,visibility,is_imported,tax_class_id,description,short_description,qty
```

And for images:

```
sku,image,small_image,thumbnail
333333,/333333.jpg,/333333.jpg,/333333.jpg
```

Always test import on a small scale with 1-10 products, and move forward only after you've diagnosed any potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

Increase all product prices by %10 :

```
<?php
   $percent = 1.10; // percentage of increase, for decrase replace 0.10
   $store = 2; // store code

   $priceUpdate = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); 
   $priceUpdate->query("
      UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal val  
      SET  val.value = (val.value * $percent)
      WHERE  val.attribute_id = ( 
         SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute eav
         WHERE eav.entity_type_id = 4 // 4 is catalog/product id
            AND eav.attribute_code = 'price' // this is the attribute type where in eav_attribute
            )
         AND val.store_id = $store
   ");
?>
```